# How to cache a stack and return a popped item using hapi server methods?

Tags: node.js, caching, microservices, hapi.js

I am utilizing an API (let's call it getNumbers) that returns an array of X length where each element is a unique number. For example, if I were to call it with X = 5, I would get:

```
[111, 222, 333, 444, 555]
```

Using hapi, when a call to my service is made, I want to return a single element of this array and remove it from the array so that it cannot be used by any other call. I also want to cache this value for the related request if possible. When the array becomes empty, I want to make another call to getNumbers so that the cache is replenished.

For example, a sequence of calls to my service:

```
myService(); // returns 111
myService(); // returns 222
myService(); // returns 333
myService(); // returns 444
myService(); // returns 555
myService(); // the array is empty, make another call to getNumbers and return 666
myService(); // returns 777
...
```

Is this possible with hapi? I cannot find a single example of this online, and I've tried various implementations of server methods and generateFunc functions to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, start with an array, if the array is empty repopulate it with the api data, then return and remove the first element.

```js
let serviceCache = [];

const myService = async () => {
  if(!serviceCache.length)
    serviceCache  = ...;

  return serviceCache.shift();
}
```